# How to properly use a class method that returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a method in a class that returns a Firebase user document:

```
class FirebaseUtils {
  async getUserDocument(uid) {
    if (!uid) return null
    try {
      const userDocument = await this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
      return { uid, ...userDocument.data() }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error getting user document: ', error)
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting `Promise {<pending>}` when I try to get the result of this function in another file

```
//need to update userDocument later
const userDocument = firebaseUtils.getUserDocument(uid)
console.log(userDocument) //Promise {<pending>}
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) as well ascreating an immediatelly invoked function to await the getUserDocument function but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: unfortunately not, I'd come accross that before but my terminal screams ```Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function``` at me (and I tried exactly as the proposed answer by cbr below)

Comment: `async/await` is only one of the ways to manage asynchronous flow in JS. You can use `then` anywhere there's a promise involved.

Answer (score 1):

Since async functions return a Promise, you'll need to `await` or use `.then` to get the resolved value:

```
const userDocument = await firebaseUtils.getUserDocument(uid)
console.log(userDocument)
```

or

```
firebaseUtils.getUserDocument(uid).then((userDocument) => {
  console.log(userDocument)
})
```

As a side note, you'll probably want to `return null` after logging the error in the catch, or at least be aware of the fact that the function returns `undefined` in that case.

Comment: When I try to await it, I get ```Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function```

Comment: That is correct when you use the first snippet. So the function that contains this `await firebaseUtils.getUserDocument(uid)` will also need to be marked as `async`. Alternatively, you can use `then()` as shown in the second snippet.

Comment: This is because you are trying to use await outside an async function. You can only use `await` inside a function that is marked `async`  unless you are using babel plugins to use top-level-await. If you don't want to create another async function then you can always use `.then` to resolve the promise.